# Issue in text change event

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have  grid view and there are some controls in which i have quantity textbox if i enter a value and leave the textbox it should call server side method.I tried by all the values of the controls get cleared when calling that method.Pls help me to solve this problem .

```
  <asp:GridView Width="100%" runat="server" ID="gvProduct" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ShowFooter="true"
                            PageSize-Mode="NumericPages" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-Visible="true" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"                            
                            >

                            <Columns>                                               

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-Width="350px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>                                                                             
                                     </ItemTemplate>                                   
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Stock" ItemStyle-Width="150px"  >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                       <center> <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurrentStock" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);" Height="20px" runat="server" Width="160px" Enabled="false"> </asp:TextBox></center>
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                    
                                </asp:TemplateField>


                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);"  AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" Height="20px" Width="150px" OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" > </asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                   
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Type" ItemStyle-Width="50px" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                    <center>  <asp:Label ID="lblunittype" runat="server" Width="50px" ></asp:Label></center> 
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                    
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Required Date" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductRequiredDate"  style="text-align: left" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);"  Height="20px" runat="server" Width="150px" > </asp:TextBox>   
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeliveryDate" runat="server" CommandName="DeliveryDate" >select</asp:LinkButton> 

                                    </ItemTemplate>                                   
                                </asp:TemplateField> 



                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete()" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>                                     
                                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" class="button" Text="Add New" />                                                            
                                   </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />

                        </asp:GridView>

 protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  AddNewRowToGrid()
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think it's javascript issue? What do you mean by client? Is it mobile app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the pages life cycle. You need to collect the value from the text-box earlier in the life cycle than when the click event is triggered. I remember running into problems like this while using web forms and once i had made the switch to MVC found life a lot easier.